# Sync 2 MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization

I have 2 MySql databases and I want keep them in sync. The problem is that I dont have access to the machine that runs the "master" database, I only have rights to read.

So I created a secondary database and I want to create a cron job to sync with the master one every day at 12:00 (for example).

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: can you _get_ the rights to get MySQL replication working?

Comment: nop ... all I got its a view ...

Answer (score 6):

Use [mk-table-sync](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-sync.html) from the Maatkit toolkit for MySQL.

From the documentation:

```
Make slave1 have the same data as its replication master:

  mk-table-sync --execute --sync-to-master slave1
```

In addition to being able to automatically bring the tables into sync, it has a --dry-run argument that will just output the SQL statements necessary to manually do it. That's great for convincing yourself that you chose the correct command line arguments for mk-table-sync and that it will work properly when you have it really sync the tables.

Comment: Any idea on how to install this in OSX?

Comment: Download it and extract the archive. Look in the README file for installation instructions. You'll also need to run the following to install the Perl MySQL driver before installing Maatkit: sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBD::mysql'. I posted to my blog a little over a year ago on an additional issue to watch out for, i.e., the 32-bit vs. 64-bit Perl issue on Snow Leopard. http://www.wombatnation.com/2009/11/maatkit-install-on-os-x-snow-leopard

Answer (score 0):

The most simple, but possibly the one with the most overhead, would be simply do a mysql-dump and re-import the data into the second database.

Comment: mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'database' when doing LOCK TABLES

Comment: Well yeah... I think you got stuck there.

Comment: Would it be possible to run this on a cron job, or some soft of automated copy once a day?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a python script to re-import all the data. I needed to change the table names anyway for the django-app.